# how to install cms, south, mptt, mptt?

Tags: django

I am trying to integrate django-cms with my project and getting these errors

```
No module named cms

No module named south

No module named menu

No module named mptt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
pip install django-cms
```

to install [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/). This will install all the required dependecies by default.

Answer (score 0):

use pip.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

after installing:

```
pip install south
```

etc.